# How to resolve the error ORA-01157 and ORA-01110?

Tags: linux, oracle

When I entered startup after mounting database it is displaying an error
ORA-01157: cannot identify/lock dta file 1 - see DBWR trace file
ORA-01110: data file 1: '/u01/app/oracle/oradata/orcl/system01.dbf

Comment: And what does this trace file contain?

Comment: Does the file '/u01/app/oracle/oradata/orcl/system01.dbf' exist? Does the oracle user have permission to read/write it?

Answer (score -1):

Is accompanied by ORA-27048, if so, most likely the data file block 0 was modified, if 11g, use bbed or bvi to change the 29-32 offset of block 0 of the data file that reported the error to 7d7c7b7a.